# How to tell Google Search Console to crawl CSR website?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My goal is to tell Google Search Console to crawl `https://event.topoint.org` in CSR.

My expected result was: The crawled html file `app-root` is not empty.

My actual result was: The crawled html file is just empty `app-root`.

The problem is: The crawled html is not consistent. Some have on empty `app-root`, some do not.

1. https://event.topoint.org/experience/1 crawled html file is not just `app-root`.
2. https://event.topoint.org/event/1 crawled html file is just `app-root`.

The Source Code: https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-structured-data-event-example

experience-page.html

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;">
    <p>experience-page works!</p>

    <ng-container *ngIf="experienceData else noExperienceData">
        <p>id {{ experienceData.id }}</p>
        <p>name {{ experienceData.name }}</p>

        <ng-container *ngIf="experienceData.events else noEventData">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let eventID of experienceData.events">
                <a routerLink="/event/{{eventID}}">event {{ eventID }}</a>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-template #noEventData>
            <p>event not found</p>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #noExperienceData>
        <p>experience not found</p>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

event-page.component.html

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;">
    <p>event-page works!</p>

    <ng-container *ngIf="eventData else noEventData">
        <p>id {{ eventData.id }}</p>
        <p>name {{ eventData.name }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="eventData.description">description {{ eventData.description }}</p>
        <p>startDate {{ eventData.startDate | date:'long' }}</p>
        <p>endDate {{ eventData.endDate | date:'long' }} </p>

        <p *ngIf="eventData.eventAttendanceMode">eventAttendanceMode {{ eventData.eventAttendanceMode }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="eventData.eventStatus">eventStatus {{ eventData.eventStatus }}</p>
        
        <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;" *ngIf="eventData.image">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let img of eventData.image">
                <img [src]="img">
            </ng-container>
        </div>

        <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;" *ngIf="eventData.offers">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of eventData.offers">
                <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px">
                    <p>offer type {{ item["@type"] }}</p>
                    <p>offer availability {{ item.availability }}</p>
                    <p>offer price {{ item.price }} </p>
                    <p>offer priceCurrency {{ item.priceCurrency }}</p>
                    <p>offer validFrom {{ item.validFrom }}</p>
                    <p>offer url {{ item.url }}</p>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>

        <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px" *ngIf="eventData.organizer">
            <p>organizer type {{ eventData.organizer['@type'] }}</p>
            <p>organizer name {{ eventData.organizer.name }}</p>
            <ng-container *ngIf="eventData.organizer['@type'] === 'Organization'">
                <p>organizer url {{ (eventData.organizer | as : Organization).url }}</p>
            </ng-container>
        </div>

        <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px" *ngIf="eventData.performer">
            <p>performer type {{ eventData.performer['@type'] }}</p>
            <p>performer name {{ eventData.performer.name }}</p>
        </div>

        <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px" *ngIf="eventData.previousStartDate">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of eventData.previousStartDate">
                <p>previousDate {{ item }}</p>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #noEventData>
        <p>event not found</p>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

The actual result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  
  <title>AngularStructuredDataEventExample</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ef46db3751d8e999.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.7611a4bdf3a12cea.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.37aaad03170db895.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.5c0adfd072d8bbc3.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

The expected result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  
  <title>AngularStructuredDataEventExample</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ef46db3751d8e999.css" /><style></style><script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Event","id":"1","location":[{"@type":"VirtualLocation","url":"https://operaonline.stream5.com/"},{"@type":"Place","name":"Snickerpark Stadium","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"100 West Snickerpark Dr","addressLocality":"Snickertown","postalCode":"19019","addressCountry":"US","addressRegion":"PA"}}],"name":"The Adventures of Kesha and Macklemore","startDate":"2023-12-16T12:45:53.743Z","description":"The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.","endDate":"2023-12-17T12:45:53.743Z","eventAttendanceMode":"https://schema.org/MixedEventAttendanceMode","eventStatus":"https://schema.org/EventScheduled","image":["https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"],"offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","price":"30","priceCurrency":"USD","validFrom":"2023-12-15T12:45:53.743Z","url":"https://event.topoint.org/event/1"}],"organizer":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Kira and Morrison Music","url":"https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"},"performer":{"@type":"PerformingGroup","name":"Kira and Morrison"}}</script></head>
<body>
  <app-root _nghost-poc-c5="" ng-version="13.3.12"><a _ngcontent-poc-c5="" routerlink="/experiences" href="/experiences">Experiences</a> |
<a _ngcontent-poc-c5="" routerlink="/events" href="/events">Events</a><router-outlet _ngcontent-poc-c5=""></router-outlet><app-event-page _nghost-poc-c6=""><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">event-page works!</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">id 1</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">name The Adventures of Kesha and Macklemore</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">description The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can&#39;t miss performance.</p><!----><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">startDate December 16, 2023 at 4:45:53 AM GMT-8</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">endDate December 17, 2023 at 4:45:53 AM GMT-8 </p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">eventAttendanceMode https://schema.org/MixedEventAttendanceMode</p><!----><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">eventStatus https://schema.org/EventScheduled</p><!----><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><img _ngcontent-poc-c6="" src="https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg" /><!----><img _ngcontent-poc-c6="" src="https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg" /><!----><img _ngcontent-poc-c6="" src="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" /><!----><!----></div><!----><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer type Offer</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer availability https://schema.org/InStock</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer price 30 </p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer priceCurrency USD</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer validFrom 2023-12-15T12:45:53.743Z</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">offer url https://event.topoint.org/event/1</p></div><!----><!----></div><!----><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">organizer type Organization</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">organizer name Kira and Morrison Music</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">organizer url https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com</p><!----><!----></div><!----><div _ngcontent-poc-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">performer type PerformingGroup</p><p _ngcontent-poc-c6="">performer name Kira and Morrison</p></div><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></app-event-page><!----> This is a live test.
<a _ngcontent-poc-c5="" href="https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-structured-data-event-example">Source Code</a>
by <a _ngcontent-poc-c5="" href="https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan">Jason Rich Darmawan</a></app-root>
<script src="runtime.84ecdfabc7408ad4.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.37aaad03170db895.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.1b11d2bb5473d983.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by "CSR"?

Comment: CSR as in client-side rendering? tbh, google sometimes uses chromium to crawl stuff. but most of the time their good old html-only web crawler that works - and they are cheaper than spinning up web browser. it is the very reason for SPA to have server-side prerendering as an option nowadays.

Comment: @BagusTesa Google hasn't used HTML-only spiders in probably over a  decade now; They switched over to browser-engine-based crawlers at least 10 years ago - Bing did as well https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/overview-google-crawlers

Comment: @Dai I think Google still use it. in the morning, i was searching `the adventures of kesha and macklemore site:event.topoint.org` and got a result, then I ask Google Search Console to re-crawl, and the crawl result is just an empty `<app-root>`. Consequently, searching with the same keyword return 0 result.

Comment: @Dai yes i know. google should have been using browser to crawl stuff. but i've encountered numerous times problem similar to Jason's case. weird, but we have to live with it. we cant be sure what makes google to decide whether to render the js or not - its a blackbox, just like how google decide the first item in search result. so to be on the safe side, just print the html as if it doesnt have javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want consistant and efficient SPA indexation there are no magic tricks.

You have 2 options:

- Enable prerendering
- Switch to SSR.

Comment: I switched to SSR. Anyway, I intend to use `@rx-angular/isr` because I have parameterized route i.e. `/experience/1`, `/experience/2`, hundreds of id and user can update the content on the go. So prerendering is not an option. Do you think `@rx-angular/isr` is the only solution for ISR or does Angular Universal support ISR?

Comment: ISR has been (re)posted on the Angular blog : https://blog.angular.io/incremental-static-regeneration-for-angular-c12745ff4b48 
It's a solid option